# Asychronous IO operation by Node

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js. I am creating a async operation in node with http server module. I want to print hello first and world after 5 seconds on a web page. I have referred this example form Introduction from node js by Ryan Dahl which is 8 years old.

I was wondering whether I have missed anything or something has changed in node.

I have tried with setTimeout and setInterval function but both dosent seem to work.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
    res.write('Hello \n');
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.end('World');
    },5000)
})

server.listen(8000);
```

Expected result : Hello prints first followed by world after 5 seconds.

Actual result : Both Hello World prints together after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually you are mixing up client and server.

The browser can only render your page when it receives the entire page. (not entirely true*, but you should think of it this way).

If you don't res.end (or res.send with express), the server will hold onto the message(see caveat below). The browser will never render no matter how many .writes you have, because it simply doesn't have the final webpage to render.

Anyway your async code is correct. If you want to see whether the asynchronity is working on the server, use console.logs instead. Whether the .write is actually sent is honestly dependent on many optimization factors you can't see.

---

*This is actually quite dependent on OS behavior.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Observe the API, it may or may not flush the chunk to OS. If its too small, it will usually not be flushed (for performance reasons). The OS then may or may not flush the chunk out (also for performance reasons).

If you want to see this behavior, write a much much much bigger string.

Literally this big:

```
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
    res.write('HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello');
    res.write('HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello');
    res.write('HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello');
    res.write('HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello');
    res.write('HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello');
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.end('World');
    },5000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting Hello and world printed on the screen after 5 seconds because the res.end would be the function fired last irrespective of where or how you write it. This is because the res.end function terminates the servers response  and only one response can go to the client the way you have configured.

If you truly want to see the output you desire try using console.log instead of res.end and res.write.